# How to speed up clock in headless Chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I work at a cyber company. One trick attackers use is to delay showing the page to evade visual detection.
I heard there's a way to speed up the clock while using headless-chrome and by that overcome those delays.
How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Edit:
They load an empty page and after a few seconds they render the actual html with a phishing page asking credentials for Outlook.

Comment: Delay showing the page to avoid visual detection? What page? Where are they loading it from? What detection? What?

Comment: @JeremyThille I've updated the question, I just want to speed up SetInterval() and such

Comment: Sorry but I still have no clue what you're asking. Attackers load a page? What page? From their server using a headless browser? How do you know they "delay showing the page"? And why would they do that? What's "visual detection"? Why and how would you want to "speed up setInterval" on a web page loaded by somebody else?? The more I read your question, the fewer clues I have about its meaning :|